# Properties of DTFT to Infer the Inverse DTFT of Altered Data

Tags: fourier-transform, homework

Given a signal $ x \left[ n \right] $ and its DTFT $ X \left( {e}^{j \omega} \right) $.

Which property of the DTFT allows you to easily compute the inverse DTFT of $ \frac{4 X \left( {e}^{j \omega} \right)}{\pi} - 2 $?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no effort shown

Comment: For my understanding, what would be some imrovements that would make this question meet the standards? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property is the Linearity of the DTFT.

Linearity means that if your input is a linear combination of signals the output will be the same linear combination of each input by itself:

$$ \operatorname{DTFT} \left( \alpha x \left[ n \right] + \beta y \left[ n \right] \right) = \alpha \operatorname{DTFT} \left( x \left[ n \right] \right) + \beta \operatorname{DTFT} \left( y \left[ n \right] \right) $$

This also holds for the Inverse DTFT.

By the way, if you want people to keep answer your questions:

1. Mark them as solved once someone solves them for you.
2. Don't use images to post the questions. Write them so the question will be independent of out of site resources.